# Wouldnt ManuallyDrop without drop call cause memory leak?

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

I am going through `wasm-bindgen` guide and i came across the [glue code](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/contributing/design/js-objects-in-rust.html) it generates for interacting between `js` and `rust`. A reference to a value is passed from js to rust. Rust has to wrap it in `ManuallyDrop` so that it wont call the `Drop` implemented on `JsValue`.

```
pub fn foo(a: &JsValue) {
    // ...
}

#[export_name = "foo"]
pub extern "C" fn __wasm_bindgen_generated_foo(arg0: u32) {
    let arg0 = unsafe {
        ManuallyDrop::new(JsValue::__from_idx(arg0))
    };
    let arg0 = &*arg0;
    foo(arg0);
}
```

But I do not see a `ManuallyDrop::drop` being called on `arg0` . So would the `JsValue`wrapped in `ManuallyDrop` be dropped unless the `ManuallyDrop::drop(arg0)` function is called? Wouldnt it cause a memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ManuallyDrop` does not stop the inner value from being destroyed. It only stops `drop` from being called. Consider a `Vec`:

```
pub struct Vec<T> {
    ptr: *mut T,
    cap: usize,
    len: usize,
}
```

The fields `ptr`, `cap`, and `len` will *still* be destroyed even when wrapped by `ManuallyDrop`. However, any dynamic resources managed (in this case the data referenced by `ptr`) will not be released since `drop` is not called.

Since `JsValue` simply holds a `u32`, no leak will occur on the Rust-side. And since the glue code ensures proper cleanup for `&JsValue` arguments, no memory is leaked on the Javascript-side.

Comment: I am actually not talking about the memory leak from the JS side. I am talking about the struct ```JsValue::__from_idx(arg0)``` which is wrapped inside ManuallyDrop . As ManuallyDrop::drop(arg0) is not called, would that Jsvaue be dropped leading to memory leak on rust side?

Comment: @raj I've rewritten the answer to focus on that part